# C# Web method is not calling in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

[image]i create a web method and now i'm calling this in my java script file but it give an path error,it is not able to find path what i'm giving ..

Web method code is :

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static int ItemCount(string itemId)
    {
        int val = 0;

            Item itm = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(itemId);
            val = itm.Children.Count;

        return val;
    }
```

java script function calling like as:

```
    function GetItemCount(itemId) {
    var funRes = "";
    debugger;
    try {
    if (itemId != null) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/Views/GetItem.aspx/ItemCount",
            data: { itemId: itemId },
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                funRes = data.result;
            },
            error: function(err) {
                alert(err.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
  } catch (ex) {
    alert(ex.message);
  }
  return funRes;}
```

while i'm giving exact path for the C# method class but it's not working give an error on console, can anyone suggest me what i'm missing here..

Comment: remove first slash (/) from url path for ajax and try

Comment: tried, not solve my issue

Comment: view folder is in sitecore folder a what?

Comment: view folder not in sitecore it is in my project directory

Comment: Make it `public static int ItemCount(string itemId)` and remove the `Request` usage, `dataType: "json"` and `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8`, and `type: "POST"` like the example below.

Comment: removed but issue is same

Comment: And you're using `data: JSON.stringify({ itemId: itemId })` as well, instead of the url with a query string?

Comment: You're missing an end quote on the url and if I remember right, it's response.data that will contain the count. Aside from that, this **should** work.

Comment: all things are fine but not map the view path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68718/discussion-between-amitavin-and-ehryk).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are few rules for ajax to work with asp.net.

> - Your WebMethod should be `public` and `static`.
> - If your WebMethod expects some parameter(s) than these parameter(s) must be passed as `data` in ajax.
> - Name of parameter(s) should be `same` in `WebMethod` and in `data` part of ajax.
> - Data passed from ajax should be in `json string`.For this you can use `JSON.stringify` or you will have to surround the `values` of parameter(s) in `quotes`.

Please check the below sample ajax call

```
function CallAjax()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Default.aspx/CallAjax",
            data: JSON.stringify({ name: "Mairaj", value: "12" }),
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //your code

            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.responseText);
            }

        });
    }



[WebMethod]
public static List<string> CallAjax(string name,int value)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        list.Add("Mairaj");
        list.Add("Ahmad");
        list.Add("Minhas");
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return list;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you use `GET` in ajax than you need to enable your webmethod to be called from `GET` request. Add `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]` on top of WebMetod

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static int ItemCount()
```

Comment: my web page inside a folder then do i need to add it's name in URL or not

Comment: No it is finding the page but you need to make WebMethod static.

Comment: i'm getting same error while i changed method to Static

Comment: when i'm working in demo project and calling sample C# method in javascript it calling fine, but there c# method on the same page

Answer (score 0):

Just Modify the javascript function as below

```
  function GetItemCount(itemId) {
    var funRes = "";
   debugger;
   try {
    if (itemId != null) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Views/GetItem.aspx",
            data: 'itemID=' + itemId,
            contentType: "application/html",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                funRes= response.result;
            }
        });
     }
  } catch (ex) {
    alert(ex.message);
  }
  return funRes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is a solution for every question subject which web method not fire. But I discovered today when there is ' char in the string. Web Method not firing.