# Call c# code behind from jquery with parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

**Ajax Code**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "LiveFeed.aspx/SearchStateList",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        $("#Content").text(response.d);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

**Code Behind**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SearchStateList()
{

}
```

The above code works fine and the code behind is called

But when I send some parameter as given below, code behind is not invoked and when I see the Firebug console errors, it throws

> NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error -
>   http://localhost:61276/App/LiveFeed/LiveFeed.aspx/SearchStateList

**Ajax Code**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "LiveFeed.aspx/SearchStateList",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data:{value:"samplevalue"},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        $("#Content").text(response.d);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

**Code Behind**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SearchStateList(string value)
{

}
```

I also tried to change modify the data of ajax call as

```
var param={value:"samplevalue"}

data:JSON.stringify(param),
```

and also tried directly with out JSON.stringify

```
data:param,
```

Every time when I tried to pass a parameter it did not invoke code behind and 500 error is thrown.

Comment: Response should be an HTML page with a more detailed description (and stack trace) of "internal error" you read in console

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917255/c-sharp-web-method-is-not-calling-in-javascript/27917333#27917333

Comment: @MairajAhmad thanks it worked, but when I searched somehow I missed the question. Thanks again.

Comment: @TechJerk if you don't mind please upvote the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try

```
var param={"value":"samplevalue"}

data:JSON.stringify(param),
```

Comment: This is how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think data content goes with quotes:

```
data: '{value:"samplevalue"}',
```

Comment: You never should manually build your own JSON string - `JSON.stringify` will do the work for you, including escaping out special characters as needed. If you do it yourself like this, you open yourself up to mistakes or parsing errors that you may not catch in testing.

Comment: Also, this wouldn't be valid JSON, because in JSON (unlike javascript object literals), the keys must be quoted.

Answer (score -1):

You can access variables sent in the data by accessing the [Request Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

```
Request.Form["your_var_name"]  // use this when you $.post
Request["your_var_name"] // use this when you $.get
```

So your code behind can look like this:

```
public static string SearchStateList(string value)
{
    Response.Write("The value of value is: " + Request.Form["value"]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your Ajax post, you have set the data property as :-

```
data:{value:"samplevalue"}
```

Subtle change, to this below would work :-

```
 data:{ "value" :"samplevalue"}
```

Comment: Would like to know why the down vote.

Comment: You didn't provide any explanation of what you were suggesting or why it would make a difference, and what you put in there is exactly what they already tried in the question (quoting the key in a javascript object literal doesn't change anything, so this is exactly the same as `data:{value:"samplevalue"}`).

Comment: look again, the user tried :-  data:{value:"samplevalue"} - In his ajax post. I suggested data:{ "value" : "samplevalue" }. Point Noted about the lack of explanation.

Comment: As I said, just quoting the key in a javascript literal doesn't change anything. `data:{value:"samplevalue"}` and `data:{ "value" :"samplevalue"}` are exactly the same thing in javascript. Remember that a javascript object literal is not the same thing as JSON - javascript object literals don't require quoted keys.