# Ajax call with WebMethod is not returning the response

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a simple code to update the database with simple Ajax call using WebMethod but its not updating in the database.

HTML Markup

```
<a href="#" class="newProject" id ="<%= item2 %>"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> <%= item2 %></a>
```

Client Side Method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".newProject").on("click", function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.aspx/UpdateCode",
                data: 'engCode=' + this.id,
                success: function (response) {
                    // window.location.reload();
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

</script>
```

Server side method:

```
     [WebMethod]
    public static int UpdateCode(string Code)
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Codes"))
            {
                int intresult = 0;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "UpdateCodes";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Code", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Code;

                cmd.Connection = con;
                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    intresult = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    ex.ToString();
                }
                finally
                {
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    if (con != null)
                    {
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
                return intresult;
            }
        }
    }
```

Its posting the right value on click event of hyperlink but not updating the database.

Comment: Did you debug to confirm `using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))` is getting the connection successfully? Also check whether the exception is not occurred.

Comment: So add an error handler and see what the error is. Or look at the request in the network panel in the console.

Comment: Have a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917255/c-sharp-web-method-is-not-calling-in-javascript/27917333#27917333

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET WebMethods do only work with JSON as the data format:

In your Ajax call, you need to add

```
dataType: "json",
```

and also supply the data as JSON:

```
data: {"engCode":this.id},
```

Answer (score 0):

> you are not passing data in correct formate. try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".newProject").on("click", function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.aspx/UpdateCode",
                data: {Code: this.id}
                success: function (response) {
                    // window.location.reload();
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code also....

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="JavaScriptSample._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>How to call CSharp function in Ajax | JavaScript Sample</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getServerTime() {
            /// <summary>
            /// Call ServerTime web method via ajax request
            /// </summary>
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                this.xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {
                // for IE6, IE5
                try {
                    this.xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e1) {
                    try {
                        // older version of Msxml
                        this.xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e2) {
                        this.xmlhttp = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                /// <summary>
                /// Display server time when success
                /// </summary>
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    // success Status
                    document.getElementById("ServerTimeResponse").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            this.xmlhttp.open("POST", "AjaxServer.asmx/ServerTime", true);
            this.xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="ServerTimeForm" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="ServerTimeButton" type="button" onclick="getServerTime();" value="Get Server Time" />
        <div id="ServerTimeResponse" runat="server">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```