# Calling WebMethod in aspx.cs returning HTML page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have the following code in my aspx.cs file:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string PostPin() {
    return "Rahul";
}
```

And the following Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/adfs/ls/RequestPinForm.aspx/PostPin",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
},
error : function(data , data2 , data3) {
    alert(data);
}
});
```

I'm using the alert's to see the returns of what is coming back, but I can never get it to return the string.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: When I alert the data, the data returned is the HTML for the page, is that normal? It's not JSON return but the HTML of the page itself.

Comment: Use the `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` attribute to see if it returns a JSON format

Comment: ya this functionality is working perfect and return html as expected....all you need to do is serialize the output (here "rahul") and then return

Comment: Please add dataType="json" in your ajax call

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917255/c-sharp-web-method-is-not-calling-in-javascript/27917333#27917333

Comment: @Izzy -- That did not return JSON.

Comment: @PranavPatel -- That is not correct, I do not want the HTML. I want the output which is being returned. My output is not part of the HTML.

Comment: @Idiot211 Have you tried `alert(data.d);`?. I've just tried your code with `alert(data.d);` and it returns `Rahul`

Comment: @Idiot211 i just tell you only the currunt code functionaliy....and also tell you that need to serialize the object and return that object and that will be diaplay as either json or xml as your scriptmethod was seted

Comment: @Izzy -- I just tried it and I'm getting undefined, this is really weird. I'll investigate.

Comment: @Idiot211 check in the browser console to see if there's any error messages showing

Comment: @Izzy -- No error messages, just an AJAX call that returns the HTML inside an AJAX object.

Comment: @Idiot211 Can you take a screen shot of what's returned and post it here please