# i'm trying to bind data from database using javascript ajax function but it didn't work

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json.net

this page is the result of redirection from another page and have the company id in the url

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var CID = url.split("=")[1];//here i take the company id from the link          
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CompanyPage.aspx/ajaxBindData", 
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: '{CID: ' + JSON.stringify(CID) + '}',
        dataType: "json",
         success: function (data) {
             alert(data.d);
             $("#GridView1").data = append(data.d);
             alert("done appending");
             $("#GridView1").bind;
             alert("done binding");
        },
        error: function (exception) {
            alert(exception.responseText );
        }
    });
    </script>
```

server side code :
//the server side have an class in app_code folder to execute every function in it

```
    public static string ajaxBindData(int CID)
    {
        /*
        SqlDataReader rd = EditingEmployee.FillEmps(CompanyID);
        GridView1.DataSource = rd;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        rd.Close();
        */
        DataTable dt = EditingEmployee.GetEmps(CID);

        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row = null;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows);
        return json;
    }
```

editingemployee :
//here is the relation between my project and the database

```
     internal static DataTable GetEmps(int CompId)
     {
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         try
         {
             SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
             SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
             conn.Open();
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Company_ID,Emp_Address,Poste_Name, Salary FROM Employee inner join Postes on Postes.PosteID = Employee.Poste_ID Where Company_ID = " + CompId, conn);
             sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
             sda.Fill(dt);
             return dt;

         }
         catch (SqlException ex)
         {
             return null;
         }
     }
```

Comment: where is your server side code ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917255/c-sharp-web-method-is-not-calling-in-javascript/27917333#27917333

Comment: Replace this line : data: '{CID: ' + JSON.stringify(CID) + '}',      WITH       data: { 'CID': CID },

Comment: it gives a new error Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this link for solution it's a gridview templatefield bind method
http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/122325/Bind-data-to-GridView-with-TemplateField-TextBox-with-jQuery-or-JSON-in-ASPNet/