# ajax script alert jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create static web method and then i try to call this into script like this

**UPDATE SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    debugger;
    alert("1");
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Maintenance.aspx/data_call",
            //data: "",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                alert("12");
                debugger;
                var re = JSON.parse(result.d).response;
                debugger;

                console.log(JSON.parse(result.d).response);
                debugger;
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(Error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

code

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static string data_call()
    {
        string result="";
        Data td=new Data();
        List<spselect_data_Result> selectdata=td.spselect_data().ToList();
        DataTable dt=new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("RegionID",typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Region",typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("StartDate",typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Columns.Add("EndDate",typeof(DateTime));

        foreach(var add in selectdata)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(add.RegionID,add.Region,add.StartDate,add.EndDate);
        }
        result=DataSetToJSON(dt);
        return result;
    }


      public static string DataSetToJSON(DataTable dt)
    {

        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        object[] arr = new object[dt.Rows.Count + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray;
        }

       // dict.Add(dt.TableName, arr);
        dict.Add("response", arr);

        JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return json.Serialize(dict);                               
    }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // data();
        }
```

when i debug code then an alert show  like this

```
function Error (){[native code]}
```

and when when i set debugger on jquery and check then debugger comes on alert 1 and then on this line $(function() { then after this directly execute on this line  means ajax not call

first i try to display data on console

error on console
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

When I try this the call only shows `alert("1")`. `alert("12")` is not called. Where is the problem?

Comment: Your AJAX request is not working correctly. Check the network tab of the console. You can also put a breakpoint in your `Maintenance.aspx/data` webmethod and step through it to find any issues as well

Comment: Can you show error log from browser console log ???

Comment: check jquery library included properly or not ...

Comment: The aspx page, which you are sending request, is either not available/accessible. So your ajax call is not returning in success nor in failure. You should check browser console, if there is any log there. I am sure, you will find something there.

Comment: why type POST?I see you dont post anything.Also can you show us how is data method decorated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917255/c-sharp-web-method-is-not-calling-in-javascript/27917333#27917333

Comment: CHECK UPDATED CODE PLEASE @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @HoangHieu check update

Answer (score 0):

This problem maybe caused by maxJsonLength property in web.config file. To solve the problem You can chnage the MaxJsonLength property on your web.config:

```
<configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

The MaxJsonLength property is an integer property that by default set to 102400(100k) and cannot be unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems in the code you posted.

First of all you don't need `type: "POST"` as you are not posting/sending any data.

So update that portion in ajax request.

```
$(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Maintenance.aspx/YourMethod",           
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",  
            success: function (result) {
                alert("12");
                debugger;                 
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(Error);
            }
        });
});
```

Or else to work it with post you will have to set

```
data: "{}",
```

See instead of setting `cache:false` in ajax request set it from a common place like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

Next on server side no need to call the method `data` in page load.

Just write it directly in class outside page load.And add the attribute `WebMethod` from `System.web.services`.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string YourMethod()
{
return "whatever you want";    
}
```

**Note :** Also another thing I noticed that you made your method name as `data`,so my advice is change it to something meaningful as data is a ajax call parameter key and it could conflict.

Comment: I told you not to call the method from page_load also you are calling data_call from ajax and in server it's still data.Do read about pagemethods first

Comment: no i mean i just post script i done with this in my code already but still show error also i commit  on page load and change name also

Comment: any solution? @Neel