# How to call a method in user defined class (C# & ASP.Net) by Jquery & Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a method in a class (C# & ASP.Net) that I defined (MyClass.cs) and call this method by `Jquery` & `Ajax`.
But it does not work.
When i call this method in another page (Default.aspx) it works correctly.
Please help me. Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrMqH.png)

I want to call FetchNews() from this class

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917255/c-sharp-web-method-is-not-calling-in-javascript/27917333#27917333

Comment: I'm using ASP.Net WebFrom

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: I sent a photo that shows the code(in question's body).

Comment: Do not include the code as an image. Just copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can call right away from MyClass.cs if MyClass.cs inherit from System.Web.UI.Page and aspx.cs (Default.aspx.cs) class inherit .cs(MyClass.cs)

```
 [WebMethod] attribute must be specified in MyClass.cs testmethod


public class MyClass: System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    [WebMethod]
    public static void Testmethod()
     {


        return '';
    }
}



 public  partial class Default: MyClass
{
...
}
```

Comment: So can i call Testmethod() from ajax?

Comment: yes, but all those above mentioned changes needs to be done.

Comment: Please show me the ajax code that calls this method from MyClass. thank you very much

Comment: same as regular ajax call .. url: 'Default.aspx/Testmethod',

Comment: Thanks for you'r Help

Comment: It was very help full. thanks again sri_rcnu.