# How to call in Web Forms code behind C# method from .aspx page javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

I have a C# method located in the code behind and I would like to call it from the .aspx content page.
The following are my code:

```
<a class="btn-button button" onclick="myFunction()">Click</a>

function myFunction() {
    <%=MyMethod()%>
}

public void  MyMethod()
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Look into AJAX.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Web method is not calling in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917255/c-sharp-web-method-is-not-calling-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a LinkButton and use its click event to call code behind method:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

C#:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Call your method here
    }
```

What action are you trying to perform with the OnClick event?